# How to create and refer to dynamically created class variable within class scope

Tags: ruby

I want to refer to dynamically created class variables `foo1`, `foo2`, and `foo3` within the scope of `sum_class_vars` without knowing what their identifiers are. For example purposes lets implement a sum function, that sums the variables.

```
    class Test
      def initialize
      end

      def sum_class_vars
      end
    end

    t = Test.new
   #add class variables foo1 foo2 foo3 to Test
```

How can I do this?

Comment: t.foo1 t.foo2 t.foo3

Answer (score 2):

As with usual variables but use only after declaration:

```
class Test      
  def initialize
  end

  def sum_class_vars
    foo1 + foo2 + foo3
  end
end

t = Test.new

class << t
  attr_accessor :foo1, :foo2, :foo3
end

t.foo1 = t.foo2 = t.foo3 = 2

p t.sum_class_vars
#=> 6
```

Comment: You should make it clear that this only creates accessors for the particular instance `t`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you are absolutely right. Just for `t` instance. I thought that @horror_fan know if use `class << t`

Comment: Like I said im new to Ruby and I thought class << t is how you add class variables. Im no interested in instance variables. I want to add class variables to my class and be able to refer to them without knowing their specific identifiers. I dont care about summing this was just an example.

Comment: in your example i would already have to know the identifiers.

Comment: @horror_fan: what do you plan to do with them, _without knowing their identifiers_?

Comment: @horror_fan: it can be done, but it doesn't make any sense. You'll be better served by an array, for which you do know the identifier.

Comment: @horror_fan: I meant that it's a nonsensical thing to want. The very essence of variables is that you know their names beforehands and are able to refer to them later individually, by name. If you don't know how many variables you will have and don't care about their names, then you don't want to use variables. Use an array.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev how do you know it is nonsensical . I think you mean to say its 'unorthodox' because you cant possibly know its useless for every single situation exists in the world.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i still want to know if its possible so if you dont know then dont comment and if you dont think its possible just say its not possible.

Comment: @horror_fan: let's have a deal. You present me with a usecase for this technique (the one you actually have, but don't show) and I either tell you to use an array or hash (most likely) or admit that you found the one appropriate usecase and show how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test
  def sum_instance_vars
    foo1 + foo2
  end
end

Test.send(:attr_accessor, :foo1, :foo2, :foo3)

t1 = Test.new
  #=> #<Test:0x007fe12c014838> 
t1.foo1 = 1
t1.foo2 = 2
t1
  #=> #<Test:0x007fe12c014838 @foo2=2, @foo1=1> 
t1.sum_instance_vars
  #=> 3
```

`@foo1` and `@foo2` are *instance variables*, not *class variables* (or *class instance variables*).

Comment: then how can i create class variables and refer to them , im not interested in  instance variables. I edited the post to make it more clear.

Comment: Use [Module#class_variable_set](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-class_variable_set) to create class variables dynamically. Your comment tells me that neither @idej nor I understand your question.

Comment: i think its that i just worded the question incorrectly due to being new to ruby and misunderstanding with some ruby concepts.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: `*_variable_get/set` methods still need a name :)

Comment: For example, `class C; end; C.class_variable_set(:@@x, 1); C.class_variables #=> [:@@x]; C.class_variable_get('@@x') #=> 1`. Notice that I've used the symbol  `:@@` as an argument for `_set` and the string `'@@x'` as an argument for`_get`. Either is permitted for each method.

Comment: Many Rubiests never use class variables, opting instead for [class instance variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions). They are written the same as instance variables (e.g. `class C; def initialize(x); @x =x; end; end`), but are defined at the class level (e.g., class C; @x = 1; end`).